# Incorrect event target

Tags: javascript, html, select, event-handling, dom-events

I'm creating a selector plugin (which can set active class to the multiple elements).

Algorithm:

1. `onMouseDown` create element;
2. `onMouseMove` while `onMouseDown` move to elements I want to select, my created element changes size.
3. `onMouseUp` get event target and do magic.

This is the short version due to shortness but I have a problem with getting proper event target. When I move to the right and bottom/top (my x axis gets positive), I'm getting the proper event target. But when my x-axis is negative I always getting `e.target` the element which changes size itself, not the elements I need.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let selector = null;
container.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  selector = document.createElement('div');
  selector.style.position = 'fixed';
  selector.style.border = '1px dashed blue';
  selector.style.width = '1px';
  selector.style.height = '1px';
  selector.style.left =  e.clientX+'px'
  selector.style.top = e.clientY+'px'
  selector.className = "selector"; 
  
  container.appendChild(selector);
  
  const mouseDownClientX = e.clientX;
  const mouseDownClientY = e.clientY;
  
  document.onmousemove = e => {
    renderselector(e, mouseDownClientX, mouseDownClientY);
  }
  document.onmouseup = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    selector.remove();
  }
});

function renderselector(e, mouseDownClientX, mouseDownClientY) {
  const top = Math.min(e.clientY, mouseDownClientY);
  const left = Math.min(e.clientX, mouseDownClientX)
  const width = Math.abs(e.clientX - mouseDownClientX);
  const height = Math.abs(e.clientY - mouseDownClientY);
  selector.style.width =  width + 'px';
  selector.style.height = height + 'px';
  selector.style.top = top+'px';
  selector.style.left = left+'px';
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.item {
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the selector is not changing the the dimensions of the items when the selector covered it, right? And this is because you're not getting the right targets for the items?

Comment: @AnthonyGedeon when onMouseUp event is triggered i need to get e.target of div with item className, and i do it, but, only when my x-axis is positive (goes by onMouseMove event to the right). When i do onMouseMove to the left from onMouseDown e.target is always an item with the  selector classname

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change z-index of my selector to lesser than my divs.